# Converting oracle's "connect by prior" to mariaDB

Tags: mysql, oracle, mariadb

I have to move from Oracle to MariaDB 10.3.21.
spent the whole day on this.
I made a query with "start with" and "connect by prior" and "order sibling by" for oracle.

```
        select * from (select * from table_name ";
        where num = 1045 ) ";
        start with parentid = 0 ";
        connect by prior id = parentid ";
        order siblings by parentid asc ";
```

but MariaDB doesn't work.
used recursive but didn't go well.
anyone can share a good idea?

> this is the original table.

```
------------------------------------
num     id   parentid       data1
------------------------------------
1045    11      4          zzzzz
1048    3       0          a3
1048    1       0          a1
1050    21      17         eeeee
1048    2       0          a2
1048    4       1          a1-1
1048    5       4          a1-1-1
1048    6       3          a3-1
------------------------------------
```

> and I won't make the same result with MariaDB.

```
------------------------------------
num     id   parentid       data1
------------------------------------
1048    1       0          a1
1048    4       1          a1-1
1048    5       4          a1-1-1
1048    2       0          a2
1048    3       0          a3
1048    6       3          a3-1
-------------------------------------
```

any good ideas?
thanks always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use MariaDB, but as I see in [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) it supports recursive common table expressions. So you can write something like:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select num, id, parentid, data1 from table_name where parentid = 0 and num = 1048
  union all 
  select t.num, t.id, t.parentid, t.data1 
    from table_name t join rcte on t.parentid = rcte.id and t.num = rcte.num)
select * from rcte
```

**<sup>[MariaDB dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=54ae9e3f0feba77e069f831e2c51a1dc)</sup>**

**<sup>[Oracle dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da8aa1d7b56d691ccffb30baba0aa18e)</sup>**

If you want to reproduce Oracle `order by siblings` you need to create *hierarchy column* and use it for ordering:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select cast(id as char) AS hierarchy, num, id, parentid, data1 
    from table_name where parentid = 0 and num = 1048
  union all 
  select concat(rcte.hierarchy, '-', t.id), t.num, t.id, t.parentid, t.data1 
    from table_name t join rcte on t.parentid = rcte.id and t.num = rcte.num)
select * 
   from rcte
   order by hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like common table expressions are the new way to go with this:

- https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/connect-by-is-dead-long-live-cte-in-mariadb-server-10-2/